# What is wrong with this code to find the difference between 2 python tuples of datetime?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 2 tuples containing datetime in python.

```
Time_A = ((datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 10, 17, 3, 25),),)
Time_B = ((datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 10, 17, 5, 32),),)
```

I want to find the time difference between these 2 variables. So, I run the code below;

```
TimeGap = Time_B - Time_A
```

Unfortunately, an exception error is caught at this point. The error is `TypeError("unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'tuple'",)`

How do I find the time difference between `Time_A` and `Time_B` in python?

I am using python 2.7

Comment: when the error is typographical and  very obvious you are always in danger of getting downvoted.

Comment: These are not "time variables", these are tuples containing tuples containing `datetime` objects. The `datetime` objects are `Time_A[0][0]` and `Time_B[0][0]`. And yes, it's still very obvious...

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers: You are right. I have corrected the question accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: @user768421: it's still very obvious, from both the representation and the exception's message, so you deserves the downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks to me like a tuple of tuples with the information you want, so you could try:

`TimeGap = Time_B[0][0] - Time_A[0][0]`